# Fetch inside a object.map() returning after map is done

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `cardsList` that is an object got from a `fetch()`.
I do a mapping on cardList and to each one I make a new request getting more information.
I got a really strange situation:
Map is synchronous, but it will first print 'Log2' and after 'Log1'.

After all, when I print `cardsList` I see all `cardInfo` object information, but if try to access it like `cardsList[0].cardInfo` I got undefined.

Do you know what is going on?

*Obs: I tried with await in `fetchCardsInfo`, but I got the same situation: I see the informations when I print but I cannot access it.

```
buscarCartoes = async () => {
    let cardsList = await CodeConnectRequests.fetchCardsList()

    cardsList.map((card) => {
        const cardInfo = CodeConnectRequests.fetchCardsInfo(card.cartao.tkCartao)
        cardInfo.then(data=>{
            console.log('Log1')
            card['cardInfo'] = data                   
        })

        return card
    })

    console.log('Log2')
    console.log(cardsList)// Here I can see cardInfo infs
    console.log(cardsList[0].cardInfo)// But hete cardInfo will be undefined
}
```

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array (and leaves the subject unchanged)

Comment: Also you're trying to build the array elements inside the `.then()` callback, which does not make sense. You should `await` that `fetchCardsInfo()` request and build the array that way.

Comment: I think `fetchCardsInfo` is async function that's why `Log2` is printed first then `Log1`. Can you please share what you are getting for `console.log(cardsList)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is your friend

```
buscarCartoes = async () => {
    let cardsList = await CodeConnectRequests.fetchCardsList()

    // wait for nested requests to fulfill
    await Promise.all(cardsList.map(async (card) => { // Notice callback is async
        card.cardInfo = await CodeConnectRequests.fetchCardsInfo(card.cartao.tkCartao)
        return card
    })

    console.log('Log2')
    console.log(cardsList)// Here I can see cardInfo infs
    console.log(cardsList[0].cardInfo)// But hete cardInfo will be undefined
}
```

Comment: Worked pretty well! Thank!

I found a solution before your comment, but I knew it wasn't the better:

```
cardsList.map((card, index) => {
            const cardInfo = CodeConnectRequests.fetchCardsInfo(card.cartao.tkCartao)

            cardInfo.then(data => {

                card['cardInfo'] = data

                if (index == cardsList.length - 1) {
                    this.props.setCardsList(cardsList)
                    this.props.changeScreen(2)
                }
            })

            return card
        })
```

Comment: @LucasMendesMotaDaFonseca Glad I could help.